# Data values adding upon using SUM(column field) - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm trying to get the SUM of one column field and another SUM with another column field. The problem is, when the query executed the numbers are adding up....

I have different types, think of it as the types has their own value and they are encoded manually which means there is **no TYPE table** but I have a type column. Each type has a different amount and when I want to get the total of the type number.. I just have to call it (e.g where type = "4")

I only want to get the Sum or Total of the column with their respective types but I'm getting a different result because they're adding up.. can anyone give me ideas how to do this? :( Thank you.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.FIRSTNAME, SUM(a.AMOUNT) as TRANSACT, SUM(c.AMOUNT) as 
CALCULATED FROM GNDSALE a 
INNER JOIN emp b ON a.ID= b.ID 
INNER JOIN gndsale c ON c.ID= b.ID 
where a.type = "43" and c.type = "4"
group by a.ID
```

Here is the result I got:

[image]

Here is the TRANSACTED query where the **type is 43**
: 
[image]

Here is the Calculated query where the **type is 4**

[image]

What I want to get is the result of Transacted and Calculated without the query adding them together.

Comment: Is wour  `group by` clause wrong? Shouldn't it be `group by b.FIRSTNAME`? Maybe show us your schema.

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result?

Comment: added sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Separate out the sum(c) by using a sub query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A,B,C;

CREATE TABLE A(ID INT, AMOUNT INT, TYPE INT);

CREATE TABLE B(ID INT, FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(10));

CREATE TABLE C(ID INT, AMOUNT INT,TYPE INT);

INSERT INTO A VALUES
(1,10,43),(1,10,50),(2,20,43),(2,20,43);

INSERT INTO B VALUES (1,'AAA'),(2,'BBB');

INSERT INTO C VALUES (1,100,4),(2,200,4);

SELECT a.ID, b.FIRSTNAME, SUM(a.AMOUNT) as TRANSACT, (SELECT SUM(c.AMOUNT) FROM C WHERE C.ID = A.ID AND C.TYPE = 4) as CALCULATED 
FROM  a 
INNER JOIN b ON a.ID= b.ID 
#INNER JOIN c ON c.ID= A.ID 
where a.type = "43" #and c.type = "4"
group by a.ID;
```

Result

```
+------+-----------+----------+------------+
| ID   | FIRSTNAME | TRANSACT | CALCULATED |
+------+-----------+----------+------------+
|    1 | AAA       |       10 |        100 |
|    2 | BBB       |       40 |        200 |
+------+-----------+----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: OMG! IT WORKED!!! My head is getting dizzy from all the queries I've tried so far.... THANK YOU!! :D